# ERROR 'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-python-sdk

I was trying to collect the List of Deny Assignments present in a particular tenant, so I passed the required arguments here:

```
tenant_id = arguments['tenant_id']
client_id = arguments['client_id']
client_secret = arguments['client_secret']
```

I created `ClientSecretCredentials` here:

```
csc = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id,
                             client_id=client_id,
                             client_secret=client_secret)
```

From some other code, I have received a list of subscription IDs:

```
for subscription_id in subscription_id_list:
    resource_client = authenticate.resource_client(subscription_id)
    resources_groups = get_all_resource_groups_detail(resource_client)
```

I am able to get `resourceGroups` in that subscription id using this code:

```
    amc = AuthorizationManagementClient(csc, subscription_id)
    for resource_group in resources_groups:
        denylocks = amc.deny_assignments.list_for_resource_group(resource_group)
        try:
```

Here, it creates an error (`denylocks`); I am getting:

> <azure.mgmt.authorization.v2018_07_01_preview.models._paged_models.DenyAssignmentPaged object>

When I loop over the list of that object, it gives the error

> :ERROR 'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute
> 'signed_session'

```
for locks in denylocks:
    print(locks)
    except Exception as exc:
    logger.error(exc)
```

Answer (score 3):

> 'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'

To resolve above error, according to [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/migration_guide.md):

- A client expecting an `azure-common` credential will raise an error like `'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'` when given an `azure-identity` credential.

So, try following code snippet according to [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/migration_guide.md#service-principal-authentication):

- `azure-common` uses `ServicePrincipalCredentials` to authenticate a service principal:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id, client_secret, tenant=tenant_id)
```

Alternatively, you can upgrade `azure.mgmt.authorization` to the latest version and continue using `ClientSecretCredential` of `azure-identity`.

Comment: Yep, it resolved

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `azure.mgmt.resource` package, its latest version have some issue.

Try the following command:
`pip install azure.mgmt.resource==21.2.1`